# Can't pass value from one function to another - WordPress ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I want to check if select field changed it's value after post editing, and if it is, then to send an email to admin.

I saved previous value to a variable $pre_status_eksperimenta using acf/pre_save_post, like this:

```
function action_pre_post_update( $post_id ) { 
    $pre_status_eksperimenta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'status', true);
};          
add_action( 'acf/pre_save_post', 'action_pre_post_update', 10, 1 );
```

When I var_dump($pre_status_eksperimenta) I get correct value, wich means it works.

Then I want to pass that to a acf/save_post hook and check if there was a change, but now when I var_dump($pre_status_eksperimenta) I get NULL

```
function status_change_notification($ID) {
    var_dump($pre_status_eksperimenta);
    die();
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'status_change_notification', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its about variable scope. You should global it when you use it in another function.

```
function action_pre_post_update( $post_id ) { 
    global $pre_status_eksperimenta;
    $pre_status_eksperimenta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'status', true);
};
```

and then

```
function status_change_notification($ID) {
    global $pre_status_eksperimenta;
    var_dump($pre_status_eksperimenta);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zairwolf :) actually I tried that but I didn't include global $pre_status_eksperimenta; in a second function so it didn't work. But now it works! Thank's again